# Use the page slug in a WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query, slug

I'm doing some custom loops that I initialize with a query like this

```
$the_query = new WP_Query('page_id=266');
```

It works fine. It's just I'ld to call my page with its slug and not its ID.

Would it be possible ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `pagename=` to query by slug. See [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) for full list of valid arguments.